# Entity error with calling Count() after GroupJoin

Tags: c#, entity-framework, left-join, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I need to perform a count after a GroupJoin.

```
var query = _context.Users.GroupJoin(_context.Customers, u => u.Id, c => c.UserId, (u, c) => u);

int count = query.Count();
```

When the count line gets executed, I get the error:

Expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[MyClass]]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]'

If I use a regular Join(), everything works fine. 
Using Entity Core 1.0

Any ideas?

**update: StackTrace:**

at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateLambdaArgs(Type delegateType, Expression& body, ReadOnlyCollection'1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, String name, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable'1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, Boolean tailCall, IEnumerable'1 parameters)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda[TDelegate](Expression body, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateExecutorLambdaTResults
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass19_0'1.b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func'1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Count[TSource](IQueryable'1 source)
   at MyProject.Services.User.UserService.SearchUsers(ContactSearchCriteriaDto cscd) in C:\Users\john-luke.laue\repositories\MyProject\src\Services\User\UserService.cs:line **59**

Line 59 is the line: `int count = query.Count();`

Comment: The code you've provided will not cause that error, it'll be happening somewhere else. Please check the error message and fine the exact line it's describing.

Comment: @Rob double checked, it's failing on that line. I provided the stack trace.

Comment: My apologies, I thought it was giving a *compile* error, rather than it occurring at run time.

Comment: I see "error", I see "GroupJoin". I don't need to look at the tags anymore. EF-core. Bug. It's a PIA.

Comment: @GertArnold what's PIA?

Comment: @johnluke.laue Pain In the Ass.